# ValueError at /change-password/ The view authapp.views.ChangePassword didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-forms, python-requests, valueerror

The below function I made says  the following -  ValueError at /change-password/
The view authapp.views.ChangePassword didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
please help TIA.

```
def ChangePassword(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        current_user = request.user
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=current_user)
        pwform = {'form': form, 'user': current_user}
        return render(request, 'authapp/changepw.html', pwform)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not *render* a response, you make a form, etc. but you should return a HTTP response, for example with `render`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def ChangePassword(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        current_user = request.user
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=current_user)
    # not in the else block
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'form': form})
```

The `render` call, should *not* be performed in the `else` clause. Since it is possible that you make a POST request, but that the `form` is invalid. If you render it in the `else` block, then for an invalid form, it will not render a response.

Comment: I re-edited the post please check as i was already rendering but still getting the same error!

Comment: @LinuJose: well you need to render it under the `else`, not *in* the `else` part, since now if the `form` is not valid, it will return `None` in the code in the question.